# Detect [(ngmodel) change to selected date with PrimeNG calendar

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-calendar

I have an input element with an attached datepicker created using PrimeNG calendar.

HTML Part

```html
<p-calendar showAnim="slideDown" 
            id="calendar" 
            [showIcon]="true 
            [(ngModel)]="myDate" 
            (blur)="onBlurMethod($event)">
</p-calendar>
```

Here I have used PrimeNG calendar tag.
I have used one hidden text box so I can pick the updated value but it is reflecting in the text box. How can I capture the updated value on any event ?

```html
<input type="hidden" id = "datePickerText" [ngModel]="myDate">
```

When the user changes the date by typing directly into the input element, I can get the value with the input element's blur event, as shown above. But when the user changes the date from datepicker (i.e. by clicking a date on the calendar), the blur handler is not called.

How can I detect changes to the selected date that are made via the `datepicker`, rather than by typing into the input element ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [PrimeNG calendar](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/calendar/calendar.ts#L111) has two events you can use: `onBlur` and `onSelect`.

So you probably want to change your code to use `onBlur` instead of `blur`:

```html
<p-calendar showAnim="slideDown" 
            id="calendar" 
            [showIcon]="true"
            [(ngModel)]="myDate" 
            (onBlur)="onBlurMethod($event)">
</p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `(ngModelChange)="yourMethod()"`.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be to use `get` and `set` properties to detect a change directly.

```
private _startDate: Date;

set startDate(date: Date)
{
    this._startDate = date;
    alert('changed');
}

get startDate(): Date
{
    return this._startDate;
}
```

Whichever way you choose you'll need to make sure you know when the logic is being triggered - and that it isn't being ran unnecessarily. This way may get cumbersome and have separation of concern issues and is probably not advisable if you have to make a remote call as a result of the trigger.